# How does the system order answers with the same number of votes?

Tags: support

> This question is answered [on Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107096/how-are-answers-with-the-same-vote-score-sorted)

Let's say there are two answers currently, **Answer #1** and **Answer #2**. At first glance, I see that **Answer #1** is above **Answer #2**. After refreshing, I now see that **Answer #2** is above **Answer #1**, with no changes to either answer.

I ask this because, in my experience, the answer on top gets more attention than the answers below. The answers below may even be better reviews about the code in question.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on the [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Comment: retagged as [tag:support] to avoid implying this is asking for a discussion

Comment: As far as I know, the ordering is random if the current sorting criteria are not decisive.

Comment: Cross site [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107096/how-are-answers-with-the-same-vote-score-sorted).